# Accessing hash value in rails session variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to RoR, I have this stored on a session variable `session[:numberofgifts]` which prints a hash:

```
<%= pp session[:numberofgifts] %>
```

Output: `{"numberofgifts"=>"22"}`

**¿How can I retrieve only the value? (22)**

I've tried with session[:numberofgifts].value & session[:numberofgifts].last with no luck. Do I need to parse it first?

Thanks!!

Comment: Maybe `session[:numberofgifts]["numberofgifts"]` or `session["numberofgifts"]`

Comment: I think the main problem here is the setting this value as a hash instead of string or integer in the first place.

Comment: @PedroAugustoRamalhoDuarte this did the trick! Thanks!

Comment: @PedroAugustoRamalhoDuarte please post as an answer so OP can mark as solved.